# MySQL and phpMyAdmin creating a three way relationship

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a rather complex database, my spreadsheet has the following structure:

```
          Colour   Dashboard 
        ---------------------
Porche  |  Red      1
        |  Green    2
        |           3
        |--------------------
Toyota  |  Blue     2
        |  Red
        |  Orange
        |--------------------
Ferrari |  Green    3
        |  Orange
        |
```

I'm struggling to understand how I can create linked tables to reflect this structure.

For each "brand" the user will have to pick from some specific "customisation options" for the various "aspects" of the car. I want to be able to define which "customisation options" are available for each "aspect" as not all brands can pick from the same options.

How would I best go about structuring the database for this scenario?

Thanks, C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

- Cars (Name PK)
- Colors (Name PK)
- Dashboards (Id PK)
- Cars_Colors(Car_Name FK(Cars.Name), Color_Name FK(Colors.Name)) 
  with composite PK(Car_Name, Color_Name)
- Cars_Dashboards(Car_Name FK(Cars.Name), Dashboard_Id FK(Dashboards.Id)) 
  with composite PK(Car_Name, Dashboard_Id)

Comment: Trying this now, I had no idea composite PK's were possible. Thanks!

Comment: @CaiusEugene You could always use a surrogate key instead (like an autoincrement), but I don't see what there is to gain aside from an extra integer in each row and overhead of adding the unique constraints yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dashboard table with fields`dashboard_num, car, colour`.  You can use this as a reference when presenting options.

Comment: Refer to @lc.'s answer for a more complete description.